# Minima of $f(x)$

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

> The miniumum value of $\left(1+ \dfrac{1}{\sin^n \alpha}\right)\left(1+ \dfrac{1}{\cos^n\alpha}\right)$ is?

Attempt:

I expanded the brackets and then differentiated and set the derivative equal to zero but it gets really complicated with that because of too many trig functions.

What is the efficient way to solve it?

The answer given is:

> $(1+2^{\frac n2})^2$

Comment: Won’t it depend on whether $n$ is odd or even? (If its even shouldn’t it be 0, which occurs when $\alpha=n\frac{\pi}{2}$ for $n\in\Bbb Z$)?

Comment: thats not in domain @aidangallagher4

Comment: Sorry I’m being stupid — it should still matter if $n$ is odd or even though shouldnt it?

Comment: It would be good to state the domain (and why).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cauchy Schwarz Inequality

$\displaystyle (a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)\geq (ac+bd)^2$

and equality hold when $\displaystyle \frac{a}{c} = \frac{b}{d}.$

Here I am assuming $\displaystyle \alpha \in \bigg(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\bigg).$

$$\Bigg[1+\frac{1}{\left(\sin^{\frac{n}{2}}\alpha\right)^2}\Bigg]\cdot \Bigg[1+\frac{1}{\left(\cos^{\frac{n}{2}}\alpha\right)^2}\Bigg]\geq \bigg[1+\frac{1}{\sin^{\frac{n}{2}}\alpha\cdot \cos^{\frac{n}{2}}\alpha}\bigg]^2$$

$$ = \bigg[1+\frac{2^{\frac{n}{2}}}{\left(\sin 2\alpha\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}}\bigg]^2 \geq \bigg(1+2^{\frac{n}{2}}\bigg)^2.$$

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

If $n=2p$ then put

$$x=\sin^2 \alpha$$ and find the minimum of

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{x^p}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{(1-x)^p}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $$f(x)=\left(1+\frac{1}{\sin^nx}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{\cos^nx}\right)\text{ for } 0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$$
Then $$\begin{align}
f(x)&=\left(1+\frac{1}{\sin^nx}\right)'\left(1+\frac{1}{\cos^nx}\right)+
\left(1+\frac{1}{\sin^nx}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{\cos^nx}\right)'\\
&=\frac{-n\cos x}{\sin^{n+1}x}\left(1+\frac{1}{\cos^nx}\right)+
\frac{n\sin x}{\cos^{n+1}x}\left(1+\frac{1}{\sin^nx}\right)\\
&=\frac{n}{\sin^nx\cos^nx}\left(-\frac{\cos^{n+1}x+\cos x}{\sin x}+\frac{\sin^{n+1}x+\sin x}{\cos x}\right)
\end{align}
$$
Since $\cos x > \sin x > 0$ on $(0, \pi/4),$ we see that $f'(x)<0$  on $(0,\pi/4).$  Similarly, $f'(x)>0$ on $(\pi/4,\pi/2),$ so that $f$ attains it minimum on $(0,\pi/2)$ at $x=\pi/4$.