# Prove that for any $x$ the inequality is true.

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

Prove that for any  $x \left(x \neq \dfrac{\pi}{2}k, k \ \text{- integer}\right)$ the inequality $\displaystyle{\left(1+\dfrac {1}{\left(\sin{x}\right)^2}\right) \left(1+\dfrac{1}{\left(\cos{x}\right)^2}\right)} \geq 9$.
Let's transform the left side of the inequality: $$\left(1+\dfrac{1}{\left(\sin{x}\right)^2}\right) \left(1+\dfrac{1}{\left(\cos{x}\right)^2}\right) = \left(1+\dfrac{\left(\sin{x}\right)^2 + \left(\cos{x}\right)^2}{\left(\sin{x}\right)^2}\right) \left(1+\dfrac{\left(\sin{x}\right)^2 + \left(\cos{x}\right)^2}{\left(\cos{x}\right)^2}\right) = 9+ 2 \left( \left(\tan{x}\right)^2 - 2 \tan{x} \cdot \cot{x} + \left(\cot{x}\right)^2\right) = 9 + 2 \left( \tan{x}-\cot{x}\right)^2.$$
Consequently $$9 + 2 \left( \tan{x}-\cot{x}\right)^2 \geq 9.$$ Which also had to be proven.

I thought that the example could be solved faster using substitution $\sin{x}=a, \cos{x}=b$ and using the main trigonometric identity: $\sin^2{x}+\cos^2{x}=1$ or $a^2+b^2=1$. So we have $$\left(1+ \dfrac{1}{a^2}\right) \left(1+ \dfrac{1}{b^2}\right) \geq 9.$$ $$\dfrac{\left(1+a^2\right)\left(1+b^2\right)}{a^2b^2} = \dfrac{1+b^2+a^2+a^2b^2}{a^2b^2}=\dfrac{2+a^2b^2}{a^2b^2}.$$
And from that moment on, no idea what to do next. Maybe the solution is too simple? I will be grateful for any hint. Thanks!

Thanks to @yanruijie I got such answer $$\displaystyle{\left(1+\dfrac{1}{a^2}\right) \left(1+\dfrac{1}{b^2}\right)} = \dfrac{\left(a^2+1\right)\left(b^2+1\right)}{a^2b^2} = \dfrac{a^2b^2+a^2+b^2+1}{a^2b^2}=1+\dfrac{2}{a^2b^2} \geq 1+2 \cdot \dfrac{4}{\left(a^2+b^2\right)^2}=1+2 \cdot \dfrac{4}{1}=9.$$

Thanks everyone, great solutions!

Comment: You understand that you’ve proven the statement, correct? The question here is if there is a faster way?

Comment: @Clayton  yes, the solution is gotten

Comment: With $a^2+b^2=1$, we have $a^2b^2\leq \frac{1}{4}$ according to AM-GM inequality. Then $1+\frac{2}{a^2b^2}\geq 9$.

Comment: @yanruijie I see now! you are a genius, thank you!!!

Comment: This is the case $n=2$ in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2848642/42969

Answer (score 3):

By your work and by AM-GM we obtain: $$\frac{2+a^2b^2}{a^2b^2}=\frac{2(a^2+b^2)^2+a^2b^2}{a^2b^2}=2\left(\frac{a^2}{b^2}+\frac{b^2}{a^2}\right)+5\geq2\cdot2+5=9.$$

Answer (score 2):

I know that you have been provided a solution by [yanruijie](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1141844/yanruijie), but I'll try to help anyway.
Starting with your inequality:
\begin{equation}
\tag 1
\label 1
\left(1+\dfrac{1}{{\sin}^2 x}\right)\left(1+\dfrac{1}{{\cos}^2 x}\right)=\dfrac{2}{({\sin}^2x) ({\cos}^2x)}+1
\end{equation}
We can manipulate $({\sin}^2x) ({\cos}^2x)$ to be:
\begin{equation}
\tag 2
\label 2
{(\sin x \cdot \cos x)}^2=\dfrac{1}{4}{(2\cdot\sin x \cdot \cos x)}^2=\dfrac{1}{4}{\sin}^2 (2x)
\end{equation}
Substituting $\ref 2$ in $\ref 1$ we get:
\begin{equation}
\left(1+\dfrac{1}{{\sin}^2 x}\right)\left(1+\dfrac{1}{{\cos}^2 x}\right)=\dfrac{8}{{\sin}^2 (2x)}+1
\end{equation}
We can now say that: $$0\le\sin (2x)\le 1 \Rightarrow \dfrac{8}{\sin (2x)} \ge8 \Leftrightarrow \dfrac{8}{{\sin}^2 (2x)} + 1 \ge9 \hskip{20 mm}\blacksquare$$
Since $1\over 0$ goes to $+\infty$, I've disregarded it in the inequality.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $(\sin x\cdot\cos x)^2=\frac{1}{4}\sin^2(2x)$?

Comment: Yes, it should, and it is. I've forgotten to square the sine. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: No problem. Great answer!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** : Let $ a = \sin^2 x$ and $(1-a) = \cos^2 x$

Inequality reduces to :

$$ (2a-1)^2≥0 $$

which is trivially true.